# Test printer online/offline in terminal?

Tags: command-line, printing

Some years ago, the `lpstat` command would report if a printer is offline. This features seems to have disappeared; it doesn't seem to be available in Ventura. Is there a way to determine from the terminal (or a shell script) whether or not a printer is online? The printer list in System Settings can display whether a printer is online, so I hope there might be shell-script way of doing it.

I've searched extensively, and can't find an uptodate answer.

Comment: Did you try `lpstat -t`?

Comment: Yes. It does not make any distinction between printers that are online and offline. I have three printers installed that are five hundred miles away and powered down; every `lpstat` switch that I've tried gives the same result for those printers and for the ones that I can print to now. The older `lpstat` gave this information; not the current one.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to get the printer status in an app I am working on.
I couldn't find anything and like you said the `lpstat` command doesn't work as you would like.

However I was able to ping my printer and if I get packets back I know its online.
Maybe this will help you.
Find your printers IPV4 address which can be found on the printer. and then ping via terminal

```
ping -c 1 xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
```

-c = count so if you want to ping it 1 or many times you can achieve it that way.
When I ping my printer and its powered down I dont get any packets back.

Comment: Just wondering whether a printer can be offline from a „can print“ perspective (e.g. while changing ink) but online from a network perspective. Besides that, good idea with using ping.

Comment: Terrific suggestion. Will see whether I can make this work in my AppleScript that displays a list of installed printers. Question: is there a terminal command that will give the IP address of an installed printer?

Comment: @nohillside ping will return packets even if changing ink or paper jam etc. as long is its connected to the network you will get packets back. If you find a way to return an "Error"(ink being changed..) Id love to see it because it would be useful to me.

Comment: @emendelson  not entirely sure. from a couple searches, doesn't look like you can get the ip via terminal, Maybe if you download another tool you can?

Comment: @Trey6 - Yes, I haven't found anything either...

Comment: @emendelson Are you trying to enumerate unknown printers?  Normally the IP addresses are known, otherwise how do you print to them?

Comment: @MarcWilson - No, I'm printing to them by queue name - I don't need to know the IP address to use `lpr` or other commands. What I'm trying to find out is whether the printer is online or offline - something the OS knows and indicates in printer settings, but which doesn't have a terminal command that shows the same thing.